# Why references have types even though they are not objects?

Tags: c++, types, reference

```
int a = 1;
int &b = a;
```

Here, the reference b has a type `int`, but, what is the purpose of it having a type when it is not an object? What if that type was different of that of the object it refers to?

Comment: "the reference b has a type int". Nope. It does not :-) It has type `int&`. Just because you stuck the `&` next to `b` doesn't change the fact that the type is `int&` and `b` is an object of type `int&`.

Comment: Pointers have types even though they are not objects. Primitives have types even though they are not objects. Your question appears to be based on a false premiss. Your final question merely expresses a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Nikos thanks. but, does that mean that I can define multiple references as: ```int& a=x, b=y;```

Comment: No. But that's just a quirk of the language that can't be fixed. Just keep in mind that when declaring references, they are "reference types". `int&` (usually pronounced "int ref") in this case. The need to use a `&` before each reference is an unfortunate syntax, that's all.

Comment: @user207421 so, what is the purpose of pointers and primitives having types when they are not objects?

Comment: @Mason what is the purpose of having types at all then?

Comment: @Purple objects are memory chunks, and types define what the data in these chunks mean and what operations these data can undergo.

Comment: @Mason yeah and primitive types like floats and doubles also have specific layouts and are interpreted differently, even trivial things like integers and unsigned integers have difference in how they are interpreted. What's your argument? Besides, all types are completely irrelevant and long gone once code is compiled and executed no matter whether you use primitives, std types, or ones you created yourself... C++ is statically & weakly typed language, and it will have a type for every single thing, what's so bizarre about that?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of having typed references (i.e. pointers) is to enable type checking (which helps to catch bugs). If you were to declare a reference as a different type, you will get a type error (you can cast it, but that needs to be done explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

According to Sumita Arora's book 'Computer Science with C++' The reference variables are often treated as derived data type in which it has a property of storing variable addresses.It is means of providing an alias to the existing variable.That is existing variable can be called by using this alternate names.
Suppose  when we want to perform swapping of two variables using references.

```
     // function definition to swap the values.
void swap(int &x, int &y) {
   int temp;
   temp = x; // save the value at address x 
   x = y;    // put y into x 
   y = temp; // put x into y 

   return;
}
void main () {
   // local variable declaration:
   int a = 100;
   int b = 200;

   cout << "Before swap, value of a :" << a << endl;
   cout << "Before swap, value of b :" << b << endl;

   /* calling a function to swap the values using variable reference.*/
   swap(a, b);

   cout << "After swap, value of a :" << a << endl;
   cout << "After swap, value of b :" << b << endl;
   getch();
}
```

Here,swapping is performed using call by reference method and the changes will be reflected at actual parameters also.Here modification of passed parameters are done quite easily which serves one of its actual purpose.Whenever,there is a comparison with integer variable and a reference variable during swapping,the possible error might occur is type mismatch error,since address is being compared with value.Here integer references are used to identify that it could store addresses of integer variables only, which is possibly a mechanism developed to tackle type mismatch errors and make compiler identify that the given address holds an integer or the datatype specified by reference such that the program runs smoothly and performs operations.References also eliminates wild pointer cases and often provides easy-to-use interface.